# Unresolved dependency in SBT: no ivy file found

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I have an SBT project which uses an internal Nexus repository to fetch some of its dependencies.  When I run `update`, I see the following warning messages:

```
[info] Resolving foo.bar.baz#foobar;2.0.1
...
[debug]     The Repo of Interest: no ivy file found for foo.bar.baz#foobar;2.0.1
[warn]  module not found: foo.bar.baz#foobar;2.0.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
...
... several irrelevant repositories omitted...
...
[warn] ==== The Repo of Interest: tried
[warn]   http://internal.url.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/foo/bar/baz/foobar/2.0.1/foobar-2.0.1.pom
...
... some other repositories omitted...
...
```

The URL shown above seems like it should work because I can open the pom in my browser without issue (note that I've modified the URL so you'll have to take my word that it works).  <strike>Even more perplexing is the fact that I only see this issue when trying to build on certain machines.</strike>  How do I go about even starting to debug this issue?  Is there any additional logging that I could turn on to get a sense of why SBT/Ivy is ignoring the POM located at the aforementioned URL?

UPDATE: My build.sbt defines the resolvers as follows:

```
resolvers := Seq(
  ...,
  "The Repo of Interest" at "http://internal.url.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases",
  ...
)
```

Also the http://internal.url.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/foo/bar/baz/foobar/2.0.1 folder has the pom, the jar, the sources jar and the associated md5 and sha1 for all of those files.  The pom file looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>foo.bar.baz</groupId>
  <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.1</version>
  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

UPDATE #2: The build only appeared to be working on other machines because they already had a copy of the relevant jar cached under `~/.ivy2/cache/foo/bar/baz/foobar/jars`.

UPDATE #3: After looking at the logging a little more closely, I believe `The Repo of Interest: no ivy file found for foo.bar.baz#foobar;2.0.1` is the true error message

Comment: Could you please take a look at configuration of your "The Repo of Interest" resolver. Most typical issues: (1) Resolver artifact path is not configured correctly, (2) Resolver is not  in Maven compatible mode. You can review your resolvers using sbt console - inspect resolvers

Comment: I've updated the question to show how the resolver is defined in the build.sbt.  I believe it's defined to use the Maven format and that is why it is searching for the pom file in the first place. `inspect resolvers` doesn't provide much detail.  It shows: `[info] Setting: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Resolver] = List(..., The Repo of Interest: http://internal.url.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases,  ...)`

Comment: Don't use `:=`. You override all settings. Just append new resolvers: `resolvers in Global ++=Seq(...)` or `resolvers in Global +=...`.

Comment: Turns out to be an issue either way.  Actually had `++=Seq(...)` originally, but changed it to `:=` later on as a random shot in the dark that I hoped might help (i.e. if some of the default repos happened to be throwing things off).

Comment: Do you have any scopes configured in your pom file. By default sbt looks for scope named compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the suggestions!  Turns out the answer in my particular case was embarrassingly simple: the repository URL needed to start with `https` instead of `http`.  I just happened to stumble upon this solution after trying to use [Coursier's command line tool](https://github.com/alexarchambault/coursier#command-line) to manually fetch the jar with commands like:

```
coursier fetch -r http://internal.url.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases foo.bar.baz:foobar:2.0.1
```

Which then produced output that looked something like:

```
Error:
  foo.bar.baz:foobar:2.0.1
    not found: /some/path/.ivy2/local/foo.bar.baz/foobar/2.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
    not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/foo/bar/baz/foobar/2.0.1/foobar-2.0.1.pom
    checksum format error: ...
```

It seemed odd that there was no `not found: http://internal.url.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases...` line and I just happened to think that maybe the URL should actually start with `https`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the nexus server is accessible via all computers on the network. Also try force updating your repo. In the past I have run into issues where there was a pom file in the nexus folder but there was no associated jar files so check to make sure that there are artifacts associated with the pom

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "force updating your repo?"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using sbt `update` and then `publish` immediately. Reference : https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/3496